# how to customize action-text-attachment tag's url attribute from rails protected to direct oss service url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

I want to show a video and i need a cover for that. usually i just need append some params to oss url, and the oss service provider do that for me. but with rails redirect url, that doesn't work.

```
<action-text-attachment url="https://www.xxxxxx.cn/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/........"...>
```

to

```
<action-text-attachment url="https://www.oss-service.cn/oss-file-uuid-...{filetype}"...>
```

we don't need the protection right now, is there any way to set the url attribute in action-text-attachment tag?